# Split text according to the number of tokens

Tags: python, string, split, token, huggingface-tokenizers

I have the code piece in Python shown below. The code is truncating `text` which is given as a string. First, the last `n` chars (e.g., 2048 chars) are picked from the text. Then, the first occurence of "person alpha:\n" and "person beta:\n" is searched and then the text is taken from the first occurence until the end.

```
def truncate_history(text, n):
    """
    :param text: The text to truncate
    :param n: The length of the history (from the end)
    :return: The truncated text
    """
    text_end = text[-n:]

    alpha_index = text_end.find("person alpha:\n")
    beta_index = text_end.find("person beta:\n")

    if alpha_index == -1 and beta_index == -1:
        alpha_index = text.rfind("person alpha:\n")
        beta_index = text.rfind("person beta:\n")
        i = max(alpha_index, beta_index)
    elif alpha_index == -1:
        i = beta_index - n  # alpha NOT found
    elif beta_index == -1:
        i = alpha_index - n # beta NOT found
    else:
        i = min(alpha_index, beta_index) - n # both FOUND

    return text[i:]
```

Now, I would like to use the last n tokens (e.g., 2048 tokens) instead of the last n characters. That means, I would like to replace `text_end = text[-n:]` so that `text_end` contains the text corresponding to the last n tokens.

I have the following Huggingface tokenizer:

```
import transformers
tokenizer = transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("EleutherAI/gpt-j-6B", pad_token='<|endoftext|>', eos_token='<|endoftext|>')
```

How can this be done?

Comment: if `tokens` means list of strings then `text_end = text[-n:]` should works - but problem will do `rfind()` and `find()` because it needs single string, not list of strings.

Comment: @furas A token is an instance of a sequence of characters in some particular document that are grouped together as a useful semantic unit for processing. text[-n:] does not work as 2048 tokens is not equal to 2048 characters.

Comment: And you should create list with tokens if you want to use `text[-n:]` because `[ ]` works only with list (or with string which is treated like list of chars). But all problem will be `rfind()` and `find()` which works only with string - and you will have to write own code instead of `rfind()` and `find()`

Comment: @furas Or perhaps first just tokenize the string with a maximum number of tokens set to n and the decode the string back and then apply rfind()?

Comment: it could work. First convert `2048 tokens` to string and search `find()` in this string - and if it can't find then convert all tokens to string and search `rfind()`